# What do the GUIDs in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Network represent?

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry

I'm referring specifically to the GUIDs beneath

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Network{4d36e974-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}

**`{4d36e974-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}`** seems to remain static across different boxes, but the GUIDs in the subkeys do not.  I'm working on a registry hack for a service in one of the subkeys and at this point all I really know is that it's not the GUID for the network interface, so I'm wondering if it matters if I push a registry change with a static GUID.

If it does matter, I need to know what that GUID references so that I can adjust the script to pull that GUID and use it when creating the subkey.

Comment: I found my own answer.  The GUIDs in the subkeys are randomly generated, which you can see for yourself if you uninstall and then reinstall File and Print Sharing (for example).  It will come back with a new GUID every time.

Answer (score 0):

According to [System-Defined Device Setup Classes Available to Vendors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/system-defined-device-setup-classes-available-to-vendors), `{4d36e974-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}` is the GUID for the "Network Service" device class.

> Network Service
> Class = NetService
> ClassGuid = {4d36e974-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}
> This class includes network services, such as redirectors and servers.

The keys beneath `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Network\{4d36e974-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}` correspond to network adapters; for instance:

```
PS C:\> Get-ChildItem "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Network\{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}\{95A5360B-A4D4-4EFB-9DEE-1C6DEEF029C5}"

    Hive: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Network\{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}\{95A5360B-A4D4-4EFB-9DEE-1C6DEEF029C5}

Name                           Property
----                           --------
Connection                     Name          : Local Area Connection 2
                               PnPInstanceId : PCI\VEN_10EC&DEV_8168&SUBSYS_83A31043&REV_03\4&61613ac&0&00E7
```

That key corresponds with my system's ethernet controller.